# Push data to array within react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, ecmascript-6

I have been trying to push data from my firebase database to array, though it appears from the login that the data isnt being presented

Below are the logs

```
[15:36:08] Get Ref https://xxxx.firebaseio.com/merchants
[15:36:08] Gladiator Fitness
[15:36:08] Array undefined
```

This is the piece of code I am trying to execute

```
componentWillMount() {
    let initialLoad = true;
    this.setState({loading: true});

    var merchants = [];

    merchantsRef.once('value').then((snapshot) => { // here too!
      // ... and add it to the matches array
      console.log(snapshot.val().business_name)
      merchants.push({
        business_name: snapshot.val().business_name,
        _key: snapshot.key
      })
      console.log("Array " + merchants.business_name)
    }).catch((error) => { // If you are planning to use this here
      console.log('Error fetching merchant data:', error)
    })

    this.setState({
      data: merchants,
      loading: false
    })

    if (initialLoad) {
      this.setState({loading: false});
      initialLoad = false;
    }

  }
```

Comment: Your console.log should show the position of the array you want to check: merchants[0].business.name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `setState` must be inside the `value` callback:

```
var merchants = [];

merchantsRef.once('value').then((snapshot) => { // here too!
  // ... and add it to the matches array
  console.log(snapshot.val().business_name)
  merchants.push({
    business_name: snapshot.val().business_name,
    _key: snapshot.key
  })
  console.log("Array " + merchants.business_name)
  this.setState({
    data: merchants,
    loading: false
  })
}).catch((error) => { // If you are planning to use this here
  console.log('Error fetching merchant data:', error)
})
```

The reason for this is that the callback is called asynchronously, which means that in your code the `setState` with the `merchants` array gets called before you populated the array.

---

The easiest way to see the flow is with a few well placed logging statements:

```
console.log("Before starting to load");
merchantsRef.once('value').then((snapshot) => { 
  console.log("Data loaded");
})
console.log("After starting to load");
```

When you run this code, the output is:

> Before starting to load
>
> After starting to load
>
> Data loaded

This is probably not what you expected, but perfectly explains why the array is empty when you're calling `setState` with the `merchants` array in your code.

Comment: perfect makes sense now. I suspecting that because this block of code was placed after the array, that it would have been filled before executing

Answer (score 0):

Your data is already in array, check `console.log("Array " + merchants.business_name)`, obvious it gives `undefined` cause accessing invalid element. 
Try an access first element in console, like

```
console.log("Array " + merchants[0].business_name) or 
console.log("Array " + merchants)
```